# Unable to compile MaxTemperatureMapper.java for Hadoop examples: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist

Tags: hadoop, compiler-errors, classpath, javac

I have been trying for quite a while to compile the first example from the book on my school's lab computer, playing with the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable and the -classpath flag with javac, to no avail.
Here are the error messages I am still getting:

> javac -verbose -classpath ~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar:~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.0.4-alpha.jar:~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.4-alpha.jar:~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar:~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.0.4-alpha.jar:~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.4-alpha-tests.jar:~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.4-alpha.jar:~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.0.4-alpha.jar MaxTemperatureMapper.java
>
> [parsing started RegularFileObject[MaxTemperatureMapper.java]]
>   [parsing completed 13ms]
>   [search path for source files: /home/2013/rbokse/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.4-alpha-tests.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.0.4-alpha.jar]
>
> [search path for class files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/resources.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rt.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jsse.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jce.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/charsets.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/netx.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/plugin.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/rhino.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/jfr.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/classes,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/pulse-java.jar,/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar,/home/2013/rbokse/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.4-alpha-tests.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.4-alpha.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.0.4-alpha.jar]
>
> [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/IOException.class)]]
>
> [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/home/2013/rbokse/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar(org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.class)]]
>   [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/home/2013/rbokse/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar(org/apache/hadoop/io/LongWritable.class)]]
>
> [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/home/2013/rbokse/Downloads/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.0.4-alpha.jar(org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.class)]]
>   MaxTemperatureMapper.java:8: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist
>   import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
>                                     ^
>   MaxTemperatureMapper.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>     extends Mapper {
>             ^
>     symbol: class Mapper
>   MaxTemperatureMapper.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
>                                                   ^
>     symbol:   class Context
>     location: class MaxTemperatureMapper
>
> [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/InterruptedException.class)]]
>
> [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Override.class)]]
>
> [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
>   ...
>
> [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/lib/ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Number.class)]]
>   MaxTemperatureMapper.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>     @Override
>     ^
>   [total 170ms]
>   4 errors

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to help without any code.

Comment: the only problem in the code is the following:
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

Most packages, I have been able to specify paths for, but not the mapreduce one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$HOME` instead of `~` in your `-classpath` argument.  I know for sure that this has caused me problems.

Comment: Thank you! I can finally compile this... after hours. Appreciate the simple advice